# programatically creating GridView but postback when update clicked prevents RowUpdating from being called

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, postback

I'm just having an issue I'm hoping someone will be able to give me a few pointers. I have an asp page which is programatically creating multiple gridviews on the same aspx page depending on a variable set of values retrieved from the database.

As I am programmatically creating the GridView in code behind, I have to create the gridview gridviews each time the page loads, on postback, oninit etc. I currently create the gridviews within the OnInit function of the page. This all works fine except for when the user goes into row edit mode then clicks the Update (row update) button/link. This forces a postback on the grid which reloads the grid values from database before their values are updated thus preventing the RowUpdating event from ever launching. How do I get around this? I have tried capturing the command selected via the RowCommand event but this event only gets fired after the postback, so the oninit function gets called first before the Rowcommand so the command name I've captured is of little use to me.

I am creating the GridView as follows in the Oninit function

```
    GridViewLineItem = New GridView
    If bEnableEdit = True Then
        GridViewLineItem.AutoGenerateEditButton = True
    End If

    If bEnableDelete = True Then
        GridViewLineItem.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = True
    End If

    GridViewLineItem.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    GridViewLineItem.EnableViewState = True
    GridViewLineItem.Font.Name = "Arial"
    GridViewLineItem.Font.Size = 8
    GridViewLineItem.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
    GridViewLineItem.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
    GridViewLineItem.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.LightGray
    GridViewLineItem.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    GridViewLineItem.BorderWidth = 1
    GridViewLineItem.CellPadding = 4
    GridViewLineItem.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
    GridViewLineItem.FooterStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.BurlyWood
    GridViewLineItem.HeaderStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.DarkGray
    GridViewLineItem.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = True
    GridViewLineItem.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
    GridViewLineItem.PagerStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Beige
    GridViewLineItem.PagerStyle.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
    GridViewLineItem.PagerStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
    GridViewLineItem.RowStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Beige
    GridViewLineItem.ID = "LineItemGridView" + strItemID

    strCBItemID = strItemID



    AddHandler GridViewLineItem.RowEditing, AddressOf GridViewLineItem_RowEditing
    AddHandler GridViewLineItem.RowCancelingEdit, AddressOf GridViewLineItem_RowCancelingEdit
    AddHandler GridViewLineItem.RowDataBound, AddressOf GridViewLineItem_RowDataBound
    AddHandler GridViewLineItem.RowUpdating, AddressOf GridViewLineItem_RowUpdating
    AddHandler GridViewLineItem.PageIndexChanging, AddressOf GridViewLineItem_PageIndexChanging
    AddHandler GridViewLineItem.PreRender, AddressOf GridViewLineItem_PreRender
    AddHandler GridViewLineItem.PageIndexChanged, AddressOf GridViewLineItem_PageIndexChanged
    AddHandler GridViewLineItem.RowDeleting, AddressOf GridViewLineItem_OnDeleting
    AddHandler GridViewLineItem.RowCommand, AddressOf GridViewLineItem_RowCommand



    'bind data source
    dt = New DataTable
    oda = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    oda.Fill(dt, rsGroup)
    GridViewLineItem.DataSource = dt
    GridViewLineItem.DataBind()

    'Add gridview to page    

    tCell.Controls.Add(GridViewLineItem)
    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell)
    TableLineItem.Rows.Add(tRow)


    LineItemPanel.Controls.Add(TableLineItem)
    LineItemPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
    LineItemPanel.BorderWidth = 3
    LineItemPanel.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.DarkGray

    tGroupRow = New TableRow
    tGroupCell = New TableCell

    tGroupCell.ColumnSpan = TableGroupDetails.Rows.Item(0).Cells.Count
    tGroupCell.Controls.Add(LineItemPanel)

    tGroupRow.Cells.Add(tGroupCell)


    TableGroupDetails.Rows.Add(tGroupRow)
```

Can someone plese give me some pointers in how I should skip the databind of the gridview when the user clicks on the row update? I can't tie the Gridview's Databind indisriminately around a page.IsPostback = false as if I do this, The grid will only be loaded once and another other valid postsbacks such as when the user clicks on to get into row edit mode would cause an empty grid.

Thanks

Thanks a million SomeGuy! Moving the GridView bind to Page.PreRender resolved the issue. My flow of events  used to be Page.Oninit (where gridview gets created on runtime) -> Page.Load (gridview bind) -> GridView.RowUpdating (where i was commiting the changes to database). It is now Page.OnInit (gridview creation) -> GridView.RowUpdating (committing change to database) -> Page.PreRender (where the gridview is being bound). Only Issue now though is I'm rendering an ajaxcombobox for the gridview's edit mode through iTemplate. The user selection for this is lost by the time GridView.RowUpdating event is called. All the other fields seuch as textboxes retain the user input value. Going to dig into this alittle further to see what I can find.

P.S. I can't post this as a comment under your post for some reason...

P.P.S fixed issue with Ajax Combobox in gridview edit mode. had to set the enableviewstate to true

Dim AjaxComb As New AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox

AjaxComb.EnableViewState = True

which is alittle weird... you'd think its default would have been true...

Comment: I've since made further changes to my web form. I am now creating the Gridview during runtime through the OnInit function and binding to the dataset on Page_Load. This now fires the RowUpdating event, however, the postback which occurs when clicking on the Update button/link in the gridview still causes a post back which reloads the data from database and overriding the userinput so when I try parsing the row values in the GridView I end up with the values pre-user change. How do I go abouts detecting when the update is clicked so that I can prevent the reload?

Comment: When clicking the Update link/button in the Gridview, the aspx performs two postbacks, the first immidiately after the click. This first postback occurs prior to any GridView events firing. Following this first postback the aspx fires the OnInit and Page_load events which recreates and reloads my gridview. It is only following these two functions which the GridView's RowUpdating event fires, alll too late as by then all user input has been lost. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the GridView on `Page.LoadComplete` or `Page.PreRender` events, after PostBack event handling routines. You can also try to let the GridView bind itself with DataSourceID and some DataSourceControl.