# Programmatically add OnRowDelete to a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, commandfield

I'm programatically generating `GridView`s, each `GridView` has a `CommandField` with a delete button. How do I programatically add `OnDeletingRow` so that a function is called when the delete button with the `GridView` is clicked?

```
                    GridView gv = new GridView();
                    gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                    gv.ID = "GridView_" + selectedId;
                    gv.DataKeyNames = new string[] {"id"};
                    gv.AllowPaging = false;
                    gv.CellPadding = 3;
                    gv.RowDeleting += new GridViewDeleteEventHandler(gv_RowDeleting);

                    CommandField commandfieldDeallocate = new CommandField();
                    commandfieldDeallocate.HeaderText = "DELETE NUMBER";
                    commandfieldDeallocate.ShowDeleteButton = true;
                    commandfieldDeallocate.DeleteText = "DELETE";
                    gv.Columns.Add(commandfieldDeallocate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, you can do it this way:

```
gv.RowDeleting += new GridViewDeleteEventHandler(gv_RowDeleting);

void gv_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    // Perform deletion
}
```

Comment: ConnorsFan, thanks for your solution but for some reason the function doesn't get called for me, any ideas? I've added my code to the original question.

Comment: The solution may be in this post (fortunately, the answer is much shorter than the question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336564/programatically-creating-gridview-but-postback-when-update-clicked-prevents-rowu